# Error using matplotlib after updating iPython

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

After updating IPython I constantly have problems with matplotlib.  At the beginning of my notebook I have

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from qutip import *
import time
```

Which generate a screen full of issues but the final part is

```
/Users/murray/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.pyc in _parse_localename(localename)
    473     elif code == 'C':
    474         return None, None
--> 475     raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
    476 
    477 def _build_localename(localetuple):

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

There were other issues before this which I managed to fix.  Similar things have been reported here but no solution which works for me.  One solution I found online suggested running

```
export LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"
```

in the terminal window (plus about 8 other similar commands).  This worked but everytime I restart the notebook I have to reenter all of this.  As you might guess I am not an expert - I would assume there is a more permanent fix for this problem

Comment: @tcaswell - this is not the same error as the one you have linked to.  In my case I could start the notebook and it was only when I run the cell as indicated.  The one you have linked to could not even start the notebook.

Comment: It is the same issue, just being exposed through a slightly different path.  Apple exports a non-standard locale setting that causes an exception to be raised from the python standard library `locale` module.  In both cases the fix is to manually change the locale to one that the `locale` module can deal with.

Comment: Ok - but in looking for an answer to my question I would not read a post that started by saying the notebook wouldn't open.  Same answer doesn't imply the same question.

Comment: Hence the value in marking this as a duplicate as the other question has two very good answers on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, you can put `export LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"` and the "8 other similar commands" into your `.profile` (assuming your are on Mac OS X).
At the end of this file `/Users/murray/.profile` write:

```
# Fix for matplotlib imports in IPython
export LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"
# your other 8 lines here without the # in front
```

You need to start a new terminal window. In there, start a new IPython session.